# Django sessions variables

Tags: python, django, session-variables

I'm working on a web service using django and python, I have a problem with CSRF token, this is my html code:

```
            {% for f in resultat %}
                    <div class="box">


                        <BR>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                {{ f.typeposte }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <BR>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                {{ f.diplome }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <BR>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                {{ f.niveau }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <BR>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                {{ f.duree }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <BR>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                {{ f.commentaire }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
               <div class="box">
               <form class="form_app" action="/apply" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row uniform 50%">
                    <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                        {{form_app.apply}}
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="ouf">
                </div>
                <div class="row uniform">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <ul class="actions align-center">
                            <li><input type="submit" value="OK"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

and I had a function like this :

```
def apply(request):
    user = request.user
    username=user.username
    if user and user.is_active:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("post")
            form = Form_demande(request.POST)
            form_app = Form_apply(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                candidat=CompteCandidat.objects.all().get(username=username)
                firstname = candidat.first_name
                lastname = candidat.last_name
                motivation = form.cleaned_data['motivation']
                p=form_app.cleaned_data['apply']
                idstage = request.POST.get("idstage", "")
                q1 = eStage.objects.filter(id=idstage)
                st=eStage(typeposte=q1[0].typeposte,diplome=q1[0].diplome,niveau=q1[0].niveau,duree=q1[0].duree,commentaire=q1[0].commentaire,compteEntr=q1[0].compteEntr)
                st.save()
                demande = Demande.objects.create(first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, motivation=motivation, stage=st)
                demande.save()
                return render(request,'apply.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            print("cou altern")
            form = Form_demande(request.POST)
            return render(request,'apply.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('/home')
```

I want to display the ' stages ' and when the client clik on 'Je postule' and then on OK it diplays a html page where the client can write his letter of motivation, so the problem is when he cliks on OK it displays me an error : Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I havent understand why, so haw can I do , or there an another solution to get the id of stage without using variable sessions

the first view is :

```
def get_stage_by_motcle(request):
    user=request.user
    if user and user.is_active:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Form_resultat(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                m = form.cleaned_data["mot"]
                mtc=motcle(motcle=m)
                mtc.save()
                query=motcle.objects.all().filter(motcle=mtc)
                queryset=eStage.objects.all().filter(mot=query)
                form_app = Form_apply()
                return render_to_response('resultat_by_mot.html', {'resultat': queryset,'form_app':form_app})
            else:
                form = Form_resultat(request.POST)
                return render(request, 'get_by_mot.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = Form_resultat(request.POST)
            return render(request,'get_by_mot.html',{'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('/home')
```

its a function who display the attribute of each stage, I want to recuperate the id of each stage in order to use it in the ' apply ' function

Comment: Either the function you shared is not the view renders below html code or you didn't add the complete view. Something is missing. Please add your complete view renders related html file.

Comment: oh yeah I update it now :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Didn't test your code. But looks like you are facing that `csrf` error because you are sending `Form_apply` form after handling `Form_resultat` form in `same view` and same `request`. Again, Since i did not test your code, i am not sure about this solution. But it is worth to try:

Create another url:

```
# other urls...
url(r'^form-apply/(?P<mtc_id>[0-9]+)', 'form_apply_view', name='form_apply_view'),
```

And create related view:

```
def form_apply_view(request, mtc_id):
    query=motcle.objects.all().filter(pk=mtc_id)
    queryset=eStage.objects.all().filter(mot=query)
    form_app = Form_apply()
    return render_to_response('resultat_by_mot.html', {'resultat': queryset,'form_app':form_app})
```

And your new `get_stage_by_moctle` view may be like:

```
def get_stage_by_motcle(request):
    user=request.user
    if user and user.is_active:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Form_resultat(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                m = form.cleaned_data["mot"]
                mtc=motcle(motcle=m)
                mtc.save()
                # redirect to your new url to render new form with saved object data...
                return redirect('form_apply_view', mtc_id=mtc.id)
            else:
                form = Form_resultat(request.POST)
                return render(request, 'get_by_mot.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = Form_resultat(request.POST)
            return render(request,'get_by_mot.html',{'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('/home')
```

I did not see anything wrong in your code besides this. So try this approach and let me know if it works.